# Have I installed Xcode correctly?

Tags: xcode4.3

After years of custom in-house programming on AIX and Linux, I am completely new to OS X so I have a few ultra-naive questions that I am sure any Mac developer can answer.

I downloaded Xcode without specifying where it should be installed. The .dmg file showed up in my ~/Downloads directory, a disk image icon appeared on my desktop, and an ejectable device named Xcode showed up in Finder. I opened the desktop icon, saw an icon named Xcode.app, and dragged it to the dock. Clicking that opens the Xcode IDE and I can write and run programs there. Everything looks good so far but I just get the feeling that I have not installed Xcode in a standard way because:
 1. The root directory of the machine does not contain the /Developer directory that I was expecting from what I have read.
 2. There is no mention of Xcode in /Applications where I see OpenOffice.org.app, Safari.app, TextEdit.app, etc.
 3. After a fresh login, when I start Xcode from the dock, an Xcode disk icon appears on the desktop, a folder containing nothing but Xcode.app gets opened, Xcode starts.

Question 1: Am I running Xcode straight out of its downloaded image?

Question 2: If it did get installed, where did it get extracted to?

Question 3: If not, how do I install it properly.

Question 4: How do I get Xcode to show up as an Application or in Launchpad?

Thank you,

Brian

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do following steps to solve this problem :-

1) Whenever you click on xcode icon in the dock, it opens a new window containing xcode.app

2) Drag this xcode.app icon to the "Applications" folder of drive "OSX" on your MAC system.

3) It'll take some time to copy the xcode to the applications folder. Once it is done you'll never face the problem again in future.

Cheers!!!

Comment: That was easy. Like I said, I am really new to OS X. It is now visible in Launchpad. In the Applications window it has an icon that seems to imply something like "No Textedit" but in Launchpad it has the normal Xcode icon. It starts properly from both locations. Thanks for the help and for the very quick response. -- Brian

Comment: Please "ACCEPT" my answer if you got any help from my answer :)